# Stripe checkout button ignores Foundations data-abide

Tags: javascript, forms, stripe-payments

I have a Foundation form that uses data-abide for validation of certain fields. I am using Stripe's checkout for payment which calls javascript.

The problem I have is that Foundations data-abide validation is being ignored and the Stripe checkout windows is being launched.

I want the form to be valid before launching the stripe checkout.

I think this is something to do with the button type having to be button and not a submit.

This is very much stretching my knowledge so I appreciate your patience.

Many thanks,

John

Here's the form:

```
<form action="#" name="form" method="post" data-abide>
   <input type="hidden" name="membership_type" value="<?php echo $mem_id; ?>">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Principle Contact</legend>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="large-2 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>
                  Title
                  <select name="title" required>
                     <option selected disabled  value=''>Select</option>
                     <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                     <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                     <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                     <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                     <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
                     <option value="Earl">Earl</option>
                     <option value="Countess">Countess</option>
                     <option value="Lady">Lady</option>
                     <option value="Cllr">Cllr</option>
                     <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                     <option value="Lord">Lord</option>
                  </select>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Select</small>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="large-5 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>First Name
               <input type="text" name="first_name" required>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please input your first name</small>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="large-5 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>Last Name
               <input type="text" name="last_name" required>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please input your last name</small>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>Known As
               <input type="text" name="known_as">
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>Address Line 1
               <input type="text" name="address_1" required>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please input the first line of your address</small>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>Address Line 2
               <input type="text" name="address_2">
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>Address Line 3
               <input type="text" name="address_3">
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>Town
               <input type="text" name="address_4" required>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please input your Town</small>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>City
               <input type="text" name="address_5" required>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please input your City</small>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>Post Code
               <input type="text" name="post_code" required>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please input your Post Code</small>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>Home Phone
               <input type="tel" id="home_tel" name="home_tel" pattern="(\s*\(?0\d{4}\)?(\s*|-)\d{3}(\s*|-)\d{3}\s*)|(\s*\(?0\d{3}\)?(\s*|-)\d{3}(\s*|-)\d{4}\s*)|(\s*(7|8)(\d{7}|\d{3}(\-|\s{1})\d{4})\s*)" required>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please input a valid home telephone number</small>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>Mobile
               <input type="tel" id="mobile" name="mobile" pattern="^07([\d]{3})[(\D\s)]?[\d]{3}[(\D\s)]?[\d]{3}$" required>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please input a valid mobile telephone number</small>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="email-field">
               <label>Email Address
               <input type="email" id="email" name="email" onchange="grab_email()" required>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please input a valid email address</small>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="email-confirmation-field">
               <label>Confirm Email Address
               <input type="email" name="confirm_email" data-equalto="email">
               </label>
               <small class="error">The email address does not match</small>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <label style="padding-left: 14px; padding-bottom: 5px;">Date of Birth</label>
         <div class="large-2 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>
                  <select name="day_dob" required>
                     <option selected disabled  value=''>Day</option>
                     <option value="01">01</option>
                     <option value="02">02</option>
                     <option value="03">03</option>
                     <option value="04">04</option>
                     <option value="05">05</option>
                     <option value="06">06</option>
                     <option value="07">07</option>
                     <option value="08">08</option>
                     <option value="09">09</option>
                     <option value="10">10</option>
                     <option value="11">11</option>
                     <option value="12">12</option>
                     <option value="13">13</option>
                     <option value="14">14</option>
                     <option value="15">15</option>
                     <option value="16">16</option>
                     <option value="17">17</option>
                     <option value="18">18</option>
                     <option value="19">29</option>
                     <option value="20">20</option>
                     <option value="21">21</option>
                     <option value="22">22</option>
                     <option value="23">23</option>
                     <option value="24">24</option>
                     <option value="25">25</option>
                     <option value="26">26</option>
                     <option value="27">27</option>
                     <option value="28">28</option>
                     <option value="29">29</option>
                     <option value="30">30</option>
                     <option value="31">31</option>
                  </select>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please select a day</small>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="large-2 columns">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>
                  <select name="month_dob" required>
                     <option selected disabled  value=''>Month</option>
                     <option value="01">Jan</option>
                     <option value="02">Feb</option>
                     <option value="03">Mar</option>
                     <option value="04">Apr</option>
                     <option value="05">May</option>
                     <option value="06">Jun</option>
                     <option value="07">Jul</option>
                     <option value="08">Aug</option>
                     <option value="09">Sep</option>
                     <option value="10">Oct</option>
                     <option value="11">Nov</option>
                     <option value="12">Dec</option>
                  </select>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please select a month</small>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="large-2 columns left">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
               <label>
                  <select name="year_dob" required>
                     <option selected disabled  value=''>Year</option>
                     <?php
                        for($i = date("Y") - 100; $i < date("Y")+1; $i++){
                         echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                  </select>
               </label>
               <small class="error">Please select a year</small>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
         <input id="volunteer" type="checkbox" name="volunteer"><label for="volunteer">We are always looking for members to help out at the club - would you be interested in volunteering?</label>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
      <legend>Employment/Education Details</legend>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
         <label>Are you?<br>
         <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:employmentCheck();" name="employment_status" value="employed" id="employed" required><label for="employed">Employed</label>
         <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:employmentCheck();" name="employment_status" value="self_employed" id="self_employed" required><label for="self_employed">Self Employed</label>
         <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:employmentCheck();" name="employment_status" value="student" id="student" required><label for="student">Student</label>
         <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:employmentCheck();" name="employment_status" value="other" id="other" required><label for="other">Other</label>
         </label>
         <small class="error">Please select one of the above</small>
      </div>
      <div id="college_nus" style="display:none">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>College or NUS Number
                  <input type="text" name="college_nus">
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="employment_details" style="display:none">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>Employment Address
                  <textarea name="employment_address" rows="4"></textarea>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>
                     Occupation
                     <select name="occupation">
                        <option selected disabled  value=''>Select</option>
                        <option value="Managerial/Professional">Managerial/Professional</option>
                        <option value="Technical"> Technical </option>
                        <option value="Clerical"> Clerical </option>
                        <option value="Sales"> Sales </option>
                        <option value="General"> General </option>
                     </select>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>Employment Email
                  <input type="email" name="employement_email">
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
               <div class="input-wrapper">
                  <label>Employment Phone
                  <input type="tel" name="employement_phone">
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Payment Information</legend>
      <div data-alert class="alert-box secondary">
    <strong><h4><?php echo ucwords($mem_title); ?></h4></strong><br>
    <strong><h5>Total: £<?php echo $amount; ?></h5></strong>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>
      <label>I confirm that I have read and accept the 2016/17 <a style="text-decoration: underline;" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a> and agree to Henley Rugby Club storing your personal details.<br></label>
      <input id="terms" name="terms" value="1" type="checkbox" required>
      <label for="terms"></label>
      <small class="error">Please accept our terms and conditions</small>
      <label><strong>NB</strong> All memberships run from 1st June 2015 to 31st May 2016</label>
   </fieldset>
   <br>
   <input type="button" id="charge-button" class="button radius member_button" value="Continue">
</form>
```

And the javascript that calls the Stripe checkout is here:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: '<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>',
    image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
      // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    $.post("", {token: token, type: 'charge'}, function(res){
        if(res.status){
            $('form').submit();
        }
    },"json");
      console.log(token);
    }
  });

</script>

<script>

$('#charge-button').on('click', function(e) {

var userEmail = $('#email').val();

    handler.open({
      image: '/logo.png',
      name: 'Shop.com',
      description: 'Product',
      email: userEmail,
      currency: 'gbp',
      amount: 20000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
 $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Can anyone help with this one?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem now. Would be great if you could post your solution here.